# if statement on sql c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, if-statement

I have 2 sql tables

```
 items with the desgin:
 minBuy (int number)



 purchase with the desgin:
id
```

At items i have column "minBuy" - as long as purchase id not >= to minBuy, i want to show img that display "X". when it's >= i want to display img that shown "V". i'm using sql with c#.

i have the two img's .... v.png and x.png.

how can i do that at c# with

```
  if(purchaseid >= minBuy)

   v.visble = true;
```

i heard somthing about to do fetch, what is it and how that can help me here?

Comment: are you returning purchase ID , min buy and i from db?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a case statement.  For example:

```
CASE WHEN purchaseid >= minBuy THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MinBuyInd
```

Now you can use the MinBuyInd column to determine which image to display.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an asp:Image ID="img" tag.

than you can just set the source

```
 if(purchaseid >= minBuy)
   img.ImageUrl = "url of V";
else
   img.ImageUrl = "url of X";
```

Comment: the if statement is the easy part, but how i do it to sql tables.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a little bit...when I look at the names of the variables, it looks like you are comparing an ID number to a price... so maybe explain what is what.

Comment: ok, what i need to do is - i have page.aspx , i have label that shown what is the minimum number (from item table) to open the auoction ... i.e the minimum number is 5... after i got 5 bids (table: purchase) - the auoction start and at other lablel shown img: V.